# Add a form in outlook mail

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to add a form with a submit button in it in an outlook mail which I could send to a group. Once user clicks on submit button, I want data in the form to be saved in my database. Any idea how to do?

Comment: How-to questions will attract  negative votes as it shows lack of basic understanding. Try to learn the basics on Outlook-Addin, then you can build your problem from it.  MSDN would be a good place to start - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to develop an Outlook add-in with a form region where you can place all your custom controls for dealing with a Db. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly. The [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) section in MSDN provides all the required information about form regions.

You can repurpose button controls on the ribbon in Outlook. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx). But the Send button is not located on the ribbon in Outlook inspectors. You need to handle the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865379.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of Outlook items instead.

Also you may consider handling the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx) event of the Application class. It is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.